# startActivity in onCreate()

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to start Activity in onCreate of another Activity and wait until activity2 finish. How to do that?

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        //do some code
        startActivity(Activity2)
        //wait until activity2 finish
        //another code which can be done after activity2 finish
    }
 ...
 }
```

Or I need to do `another code` in OnActivityResult async way??

Comment: try startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity().

Comment: It dont block it,am I right? On create finish then I get result in callback onActivityResult()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start activity2 like startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode).

And do what ever you want to do in onActivityResult(int arg0, int arg1, Intent arg2) on finsh activity2.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this way...

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, getApplicationContext());

        int requestCode = 0;
        startActivityForResult(i,requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       // do your stuff here after SecondActivity finished.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The " do you stuff here ... "  might also contain `setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);` ?

Comment: I suppose `new Intent(SecondActivity.this, getApplicationContext())` should read `new Intent(this /* or getApplicationContext() */, SecondActivity.class)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use startActivtyForResult method to start the activty2 then when onActivityResult of activty1 called call setContentView for the first one

Answer (score 1):

You can use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and then catch the result in [OnActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

[Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);`